# Use wp_set_post_terms() instead of wp_insert_post()

Tags: plugin-development, taxonomy, wp-insert-post, wp-cron

Since I use cron jobs for automation I ran into some problems with the taxonomy. Before I used the cron job, the following code used to work:

```
$custom_tax = array(
    "project-type" => array(
        "2"
    )
);
$mypost = array(
    'post_title' => $basicdata["Model"],
    'post_type' => "portfolio",
    'post_status' => "publish",
    'tax_input' => $custom_tax,
    'comment_status' => "closed"
);
$pid = wp_insert_post($mypost);
```

I know when I use cron jobs, can't use `tax_input` in `wp_insert_post()` anymore, but it should work with `wp_set_post_terms()`. I didn't really understand how to achieve the same thing with `wp_set_post_terms()` by reading the WordPress codex. Would be nice if anyone could help me...

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in this post? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158323/wp-cron-and-wp-insert-post

Comment: Thats where I found out, that my code does not work with cron jobs. After doing some more reasearch i found the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours of further searching i found the solution:

`wp_set_post_terms($pid, array("2"), "project-type");`